# Setting Drawable as text color raise an exception 'Color value must start with #'

Tags: android, android-layout, exception, drawable

In a `layout` I use a `button` which I set its `textColor` to a drawable as follows :

@drawble/text_color_drawable :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- disabled state -->
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/disabled_text_color" /> 
    <item android:color="@color/main_text_color"/>
</selector>
```

@color/main_text_color :

```
<color name="main_text_color">#9797A3</color>
```

But when I use this `drawable` called `text_color_drawable` as `textColor` :
`android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_drawable"`
I get an exception : `Exception raised during rendering: Color value text_color_drawable must start with #`

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: what about @color/disabled_text_color, how is defined?

Comment: `<color name="disabled_text_color">#323A41</color>`

Comment: How is `text_color_drawable` defined?

Comment: It is shown in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem may be`@drawble/text_color_drawable`: it shouldn't be a 'drawable', but rather a
'color'. Basically what you currently have is a [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html), but what you really want is a [`ColorStateList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html). Both are quite similar, but live in different places in the resources.

That being said, try moving the file from `res/drawable` to `res/color`. When you then assign the resource as text color, it should say: `android:textColor="@color/text_color_drawable"`

Comment: That seems to be the answer !, Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

In my case a refresh button has helped. It is placed in a small toolbar over a design view, near magnifiers (with icons like 1:1, +, -).